# Laravel 6, mysqldump issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-6

I'm trying to create a db dump using laravel 6. Once I run the function the data save successfully in the db but gives me following error,

**Spatie\DbDumper\Exceptions\DumpFailed
The dump process failed with exitcode 1 : General error : '"mysqldump"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.**

I tried several fixes but nothing seem to be working. My config/database.php code is

```
'dump' => [
                'dump_binary_path' => 'C:\xampp\mysql\bin',
                'use_single_transaction',
                'timeout' => 60 * 5, 
             ],
```

as this was not working instead of 'dump_binary_path' I even tried 'set_dump_binary_path' but that's not working either.

Comment: It appears that library code does not set the path of the executables when creating database dumper. You will have to either fork it and add it yourself, or submit a patch. See function [dumpDatabases](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup/blob/master/src/Tasks/Backup/BackupJob.php). An easier way would be is to add this path into system environment path.

Comment: As you told i added this path into system environment path, Name:mysldump  PATH:C:\xampp\mysql\bin but still getting he same issue..

Comment: I’m not 100%, but it’s likely that you need to reboot your PC after doing that.

Answer (score -1):

**Change your path from**

```
'C:\xampp\mysql\bin'
```

**to**

```
'C:/xampp/mysql/bin'
```

Comment: No difference in that. `Laravel` understands Unix Style